# How to use the dplyr `distinct()` function on a SQL database?

Tags: sql, r, dplyr, teradata, dbplyr

I'm getting the following error when I apply a specific dplyr function `distinct()` to a table in a SQL database.

```
tbl(P0_MAU_3N_V, "D_QNO_MTYPE") %>% distinct()
#> Error: <SQL> 'SELECT DISTINCT  TOP 11 * FROM "D_QNO_MTYPE"'
#> nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1700: HY222: [Teradata][ODBC Teradata Driver]
#> [Teradata Database](-3419)
#> TOP N Syntax error: Top N option is not supported with DISTINCT option.
```

If I examine the query I get:

```
tbl(P0_MAU_3N_V, "D_QNO_MTYPE") %>% distinct() %>% show_query()
#> <SQL>
#> SELECT DISTINCT *
#> FROM "D_QNO_MTYPE"
```

I'm guessing this is some kind of no-no in SQL syntax. What's the best way to use `dplyr::distinct()` on a SQL database? Is there a tidyverse way to do this or should this be some type of direct SQL query?

---

EDIT

@akrun I'm sorry but I just don't know how to make the repro, with the example you give. I hope this helps:

```
DBI::dbGetInfo(P0_MAU_3N_V)
#> $dbname
#> [1] "P0_MAU_3N_V"
#> 
#> $dbms.name
#> [1] "Teradata"
#> 
#> $db.version
#> [1] "15.10.0704  15.10.07.04"
#> 
#> $username
#> [1] "redacted"
#> 
#> $host
#> [1] ""
#> 
#> $port
#> [1] ""
#> 
#> $sourcename
#> [1] ""
#> 
#> $servername
#> [1] "redacted"
#> 
#> $drivername
#> [1] "tdataodbc_sb64.dll"
#> 
#> $odbc.version
#> [1] "03.80.0000"
#> 
#> $driver.version
#> [1] "16.20.00.054"
#> 
#> $odbcdriver.version
#> [1] "03.80"
#> 
#> $supports.transactions
#> [1] TRUE
#> 
#> attr(,"class")
#> [1] "Teradata"    "driver_info" "list"
```

Comment: Can you show a reproducible example `con <- DBI::dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), ":memory:");df1 <- data.frame(col1 = rep(LETTERS[1:3], each = 3), col2 = rep(letters[1:3], each = 3));copy_to(con, df1);tbl(con, "df1") %>% distinct()
# Source:   lazy query [?? x 2]
# Database: sqlite 3.29.0 [:memory:]
  col1  col2 
  <chr> <chr>
1 A     a    
2 B     b    
3 C     c`

Comment: @akrun How do I determine what type of SQL database I'm in right now? That way I can create a repro that mimics the SQL database I am in. I don't know if I have a SQLite, a SQLHeavy, a TeraData, too new at this...

Comment: Can you try `DBI::dbGetInfo(P0_MAU_3N_V)`

Comment: Also, check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9917037/how-to-detect-database-type) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5308682/how-to-find-current-database-type)

Comment: @akrun added some info to the question. Not sure if that helps to create a repro or not.

Comment: Thanks, with 'Teradata' I am not sure about the syntax

Comment: Do you have to use dplyr? With straight DBI you can do something like this:  library(DBI)
con <- dbConnect(... teradata-specific connection string)
res <- dbSendQuery(con, "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM D_QNO_MTYPE")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TOP N` comes with a lot of restrictions and using it with `DISTINCT` is one of them.  I'm not sure about the syntax with `dplyr`, but if you can run some raw SQL what if you try separating the operators using a sub-query like this:

```sql
SELECT TOP 11 *
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT *
  FROM "D_QNO_MTYPE"
) src
```

Another option if you don't have too many columns is to use `GROUP BY` to get a unique set of rows:

```sql
SELECT col1, col2 ... -- list of columns to apply DISTINCT to
FROM "D_QNO_TYPE"
GROUP BY col1, col2 ... -- same column list in the SELECT
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER() <=11 -- Get first 11 rows (i.e. TOP 11)
```

The `GROUP BY` is applied first and then the `QUALIFY`.  If you want to specify an ordering of columns, just put the column list inside the `OVER()` clause.  I'm not sure if you can combine `TOP` with `GROUP BY`, but you could try that too and see if it works.